# Is it good to answer questions in comments?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, answers

What are the pros and cons of answering questions in question comments?

If I answer a question in comments accidentally, I mean while clarifying question, should I post my comment as an answer?

Comment: Per note in my answer please describe what problem, situation etc. you're facing that is making you unsure.

Comment: It's good that you thought about how to make this generally applicable, but also please supply the question in hand so we can tell what's appropriate to do in that case.

Comment: I was talking about a general question, let's say I know the answer, but is a simple answer which can be correctly formatted in comments, should I post answer? I see people answering in comments several times.

Answer (score 1):

Wait what?  Don't.  Answer in answers.  See put slightly more sarcastically:  [Comment UI not friendly enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175192/183887)

Now I think you're more getting at the issue I'm trying to cover in this question, which is still under discussion:  [When is it appropriate to instruct a user on precise debugging steps to solve a problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179772/when-is-it-appropriate-to-instruct-a-user-on-precise-debugging-steps-to-solve-a)

If you're helping the user *research* a question and you don't really know what's going on, post a comment.  If you have a step to take that you reasonably expect will get the user over the problem, post as an answer.

Side-note:  Even on meta it's better to have a "problem to solve."  I thought this was easy to answer and have a reasonable guess as to what spurred this problem so I answered, but you really ought to explain what situation prompted you to become unsure of this.