# Should you post a probably correct answer as an answer or a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

Many people often post *possibly* correct answers as comments, because they're not sure if it's correct and don't want to receive downvotes. However, these comments often are correct and this causes problems, as a comment cannot be marked as an answer.

As an answer, it could be deleted if it's not helpful, but then it would just waste time and could be marked correct by the person asking the question because they don't fully understand the topic (the entire reason why they're asking the question).

**Would it be better to post a *possibly* correct answer as an answer or as a comment?**
*...or not post anything at all?*

Comment: I am pretty sure we have a duplicate for this question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you find it please?

Comment: OK, this is at least related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179774/is-it-good-to-answer-questions-in-comments